# Printing from the SlideMaster

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm creating a test in Powerpoint to be taken by my fellow employees.

I have a certificate in the Slide Master.  How can I print the certificate from the Slide Master with VBA?

I've taken a look at properties listed by Microsoft ([Presentation.SlideMaster](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.presentation.slidemaster) and [PrintOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.printoptions), as examples).

I'm setting the certificate to be printed from the SlideMaster, via this:

```
Set CertificateSlide = ActivePresentation.Designs(2).SlideMaster.CustomLayouts(2)
```

I'm printing the certificate slide, which is at the end, via this:

```
Set SlidesToBePrinted = ActivePresentation.PrintOptions.Ranges.Add(15, 15)
```

Is there a way to use PrintOptions to refer specifically to SlideMaster or must I refer to slides not in SlideMaster, as I currently am doing?

Comment: Print the slide, not the master. Masters aren't designed to be printed.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have followed [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iCPc8yaLDGM) tutorial.

1. Assign the slide master to your slide x (x represents the slide number)
2. Print slide x

```
Set SlidesToBePrinted = ActivePresentation.PrintOptions.Ranges.Add(x, x)
'x is the slide-number of the side x
```

For more details, please watch the above video in its entirety.

Thank you.